# Repeating a simple algorithm for matrices in R?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, mapply

I'm trying to avoid repeating some simple calculations by creating the **first part**. But I'm wondering why I don't obtain the same result as calculated by the **second part** (second part gives the correct answer)?

**First part:**

```
 a = matrix(c(8,11,2, 6,8,4, 4,5,6, 2,8,8), nrow = 3)   
nr = nrow(a)
nc = ncol(a)
mc = colMeans(a)
mr = rowMeans(a)
gr = mean(a)

(m = matrix(c(a[rep(1:nr, nr), rep(1:nc, each = nc)] - mr[rep(1:nr, nr)] - 
mc[rep(1:nc, each = nc)] + gr), nrow = nr, ncol = nc))     ## This is NOT correct answer !!
```

**Second part:**

```
a11 <- a[1, 1] - mr[1] - mc[1] + gr
a21 <- a[2, 1] - mr[2] - mc[1] + gr
a31 <- a[3, 1] - mr[3] - mc[1] + gr
a12 <- a[1, 2] - mr[1] - mc[2] + gr
a22 <- a[2, 2] - mr[2] - mc[2] + gr
a32 <- a[3, 2] - mr[3] - mc[2] + gr
a13 <- a[1, 3] - mr[1] - mc[3] + gr
a23 <- a[2, 3] - mr[2] - mc[3] + gr
a33 <- a[3, 3] - mr[3] - mc[3] + gr
a14 <- a[1, 4] - mr[1] - mc[4] + gr
a24 <- a[2, 4] - mr[2] - mc[4] + gr
a34 <- a[3, 4] - mr[3] - mc[4] + gr

g = paste0("a", rep(1:3, 3), rep(1:4, each = 3))
(m = matrix(c(mget(g)), nr = 3, ncol = 4))             ## This is the correct answer !!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `outer` to calculate the differences:

```
myMat <- a - outer(mr, mc, "+") + gr
myMat

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    2    1    0   -3
[2,]    2    0   -2    0
[3,]   -4   -1    2    3
```

rebuild m so that it is not a list

```
m = matrix(unlist(mget(g)), nr = 3, ncol = 4)
```

Now, check that they are identical:

```
identical(m, myMat)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: @rnorouzian This is the same as `a[., .] - (mr[.] + mc[.]) + gr`.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it has to do with the way R works with matrices.

```
m = matrix(c(1,2,3,4), nrow =2)
```

Matrices get filled up by columns, so in my case:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 3 \
2 & 4 
\end{pmatrix} $$

If you want it to be otherwise, you can specify do it like this:

```
m = matrix(c(1,2,3,4),nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
```

that should work.